# MsDeploy.exe ERROR_FILE_IN_USE Error - Octopus Deploy

Tags: msdeploy, octopus-deploy

I am trying to create nuget packages on every builds with Nugetter in VS 2013 and TFS 2013.
Everything is fine. I am creating the packages and putting to a fixed location.
and getting these packeges with Octopus. 
On Octopus I have environments and projects. And I can create Releases.
But when I wanted to deploy releases to an environment I am getting the below error.

I am stuck! What can I do for this? Any help?

Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
Error 17:58:30
More Information: The file 'Website.zip' is in use. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
Error 17:58:30
Error: The process cannot access '[SomePath]\WebSites\test.octopus.com\Debug\Website.zip' because it is being used by another process.
Error 17:58:30
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
Error 17:58:30
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProviderBase.Delete(Boolean whatIf)
Error 17:58:30
Error count: 1.

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this error in the past it could be one of several things:

First, make sure the file isn't getting marked as read-only.

Next, from time-to-time I have to stop the IIS application pools before copying files to the destination. Then restart when the copy is finished.

Finally, Could some virus scanner be locking the file while you're trying to access it?